# Unity Webgl js File Not Found

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am working on some WebGL project and then I pushed my project on some webserver. When I open the website ( otom.playback.com.tr ) I took some errors like here below,

> http://otom.playback.com.tr/Release/deneme.js Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> http://otom.playback.com.tr/Release/deneme.jsgz Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> UnityLoader.js:1 Uncaught incorrect header check

The first error says me deneme.js does not found in the webserver. But unity does not give me a js file. I added all files as mime type but still doesn't work.

What I must to do for this errors. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Unity's official documentation

> The Development or Release folder contains the following files (the
>   MyProject file name represents the name of your project). (Note that
>   if you make a release build, files in this folder are compressed and
>   have a .gz suffix. See the comments on Distribution size below.)
>
> - A MyProject.js JavaScript file containing the code for your player.
> - A MyProject.mem file containing a binary image to initialize the heap memory for your player.
> - A MyProject.data file containing the asset data and scenes.
> - A UnityLoader.js file containing the code needed to
>     load up the Unity content in the web page.le containing the code
>     needed to load up the Unity content in the web page.

- If your JS files are missing you should rebuild the Project and make sure it builds without any error.
- Make sure your host allows access to JS files
- Set up a local web server to test your Project easier/faster before deploying to the web

*More information can be found here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html*

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem, i put this `web.config` in project folder or you can add manually the mime in IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".memgz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".data" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".datagz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jsgz" mimeType="application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Had to add one for `.unityweb` but your solution worked great for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also got this - on 5.3.4f1 with Edge.

My solution - using 7Zip, I extracted the jsgz files (and the other gz files) to the folder and then the player worked.

I think the default compression handling doesn't work if you're using something lame like Dropbox - like I am :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct access to your web server probably you should setup MIMEs. In my case IIS simply did not know what to do with *.mem, *.data, and other all that garbage.